# How to call an extension method from own class without casting?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I'm trying to call an *extension method* on my own class, but it fails to compile. Consider the following lines of code:

```
public interface IHelloWorld
{
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string HelloWorld(this IHelloWorld ext)
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}

public class Test : IHelloWorld
{
    public string SaySomething()
    {
        return HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Basically I'm extending on the interface. I keep getting this error:

```
The name 'HelloWorld' does not exist in the current context
```

Can anybody explains this to me? When I do a cast all seems well:

`return ((Test)this).HelloWorld();`

Any explanations?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *cast* isn't necessary - the `this` part is. So this works fine:

```
return this.HelloWorld();
```

Section 7.6.5.2 explicitly talks about method invocations of the form

```
expr.identifier ( )
expr.identifier ( args )
expr.identifier < typeargs > ( )
expr.identifier < typeargs > ( args )
```

This invocation:

```
HelloWorld()
```

isn't of that form, as there's no expression involved.

It's not immediately clear to me *why* the language was designed that way (i.e. why the "implicit this" was excluded) and maybe Eric Lippert will add an answer to that effect later. (The answer may well be along the lines of "because it would have taken a long time to spec, implement and test, for relatively little benefit.") However, this answer at least shows that the C# compiler is sticking to the spec...

Comment: First off, I note that if you are the person writing the call site `this.HelloWorld();` then you're the person who could be adding the `HelloWorld` method to the current type.  Why use an extension method at all when you could use an instance method? The point of extension methods is to enable you to add methods to types that you *do not already own*.

Comment: Second, remember that extension methods were invented to make LINQ work. Every syntactic transformation of a query expression produces an expression of the form `expr.identifier(...)`. There's never a case where an "implicit this" is going to be inserted before `Where` or `Select` or whatever.

Comment: @EricLippert: I think the use case of "add a utility method to an interface, which works in terms of members of the interface" is a slight exception to the first case. We don't (or at least might not) really want to add an instance method to either the interface or the implementation. If we could add instance methods *with bodies* to the interface (as discussed by one of the CLR team in an interview once - Vance Morrison perhaps?) then it would presumably be entirely reasonable to just call that method. Extension methods can be used as an imperfect workaround to the interface body limitation.

Comment: @EricLippert: The second point (around LINQ) makes perfect sense *for LINQ*... I guess the question becomes whether extension methods *should* have been designed with a bias towards "just enough to make LINQ work". That's potentially where the cost/benefit analysis comes in, of course.

Comment: @Lippert: "The point of extension methods is to enable you to add methods to types that you do not already own" I sometimes use extension methods as a way to add a common default implementation for methods of interfaces. So `IPlayer` declares `void Resign()` (among other methods), `static class PlayerRoutines` implements `void Resign(this IPLayer)` and `ChessPlayer: IPlayer` and `BridgePlayer: IPlayer` can share the `Resign()` code even though the classes dont share a common ancestor. Is this bad practice?

Comment: @AliFerhat: I don't know that it is a *bad* practice but it certainly strikes me as an *odd* practice. If I saw it in a code review I'd ask for an explanation of why the method isn't (1) in a common base class, or (2) already a method of the interface.  (And apropos of nothing: can you resign in Bridge? How is it scored if you do? What if East resigns but West does not want to?)

Comment: @Eric: There are times when you would [want the common instance-methods without the common base-class](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552410/move-lots-of-helpful-methods-from-list-to-ilist-using-extension-methods).

Comment: @Lippert: "If I saw it in a code review I'd ask for an explanation of why the method isn't (..) already a method of the interface" I would put it in the interface declaration if I could, but it's illegal in C#, so using an extension method (even when I own all the codes) is the only way I know. Bridge: Yeah, it's usually the other way around, i.e. North opens her cards and says she wins the rest.

Answer (score 3):

`this.HelloWorld();` works with **no casting**.

Remember how Extension methods work:

You use an object and compiler would know the type then it could resolve it to the extension method. If no object is used, then it would not be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but too long to fit in the comment section...

Let's take the following example, that I think is pretty common:

```
public class DoubleSet : List<double>
{
    public IEnumerable<double> Square()
    {
        return this.Select( x => x*x );
    }
}
```

It is a perfectly valid point that the `this` is not necessary for the compiler to interpret the Select method properly.

However I think that in some ways, imposing the dot notation highlights the fact that we're dealing with an extension method, and that as such, **the extension method will only access the members of the current instance through public accessors, even if you're calling it within the private scope of the class**.

It makes explicit to the code reader that the extension method will treat the "this" instance as if it didn't know anything of its internal state. And indeed the class of the object is completely unknown to the extension method (as the extension method only knows the interface)

If the code was only:

```
    public IEnumerable<double> Square()
    {
        return Select( x => x*x );
    }
```

it would be much less obvious that you're dealing with IEnumerable.Select that is actually calling the IList.GetEnumerator and getting every element one by one to call the x => x*x function.